# Optimizing select case query

Tags: mysql, optimization

Is there a way I can rewrite or optimize this query?

```
SELECT
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '001' THEN value END) Col1,  
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '002' THEN value END) Col2,
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '003' THEN value END) Col3,  
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '004' THEN value END) Col4,
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '005' THEN value END) Col5,  
    MIN(CASE WHEN id = '006' THEN value END) Col6

FROM table
WHERE id IN (001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006) and

DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) "2014-11-12"

AND

value > -5 OR value > 5


GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), MINUTE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) DIV 60
```

It was working fine before but after I added the

```
AND

value > -5 OR value > 5
```

it stopped executing and is just timing out.
any suggestions on how i can make this query faster?

====

Update, I ran the this query and did not close the window, it did execute but it took too long
`Query took 323.0750 seconds.`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like u missed the clips there:

```
...
AND

(value > -5 OR value > 5)
...
```

If u dont set the clips, the SQL is defined as:

```
WHERE id IN (001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006) and

DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) "2014-11-12"

AND

value > -5
```

AND

```
OR value > 5
```

//EDIT:

btw: Why do u search > -5 OR > 5? > -5 implies > 5...

Comment: oh wow that made a difference. but question, how do i do it if for example on this first case in select  `MIN(CASE WHEN id = '001' THEN value END) Col1` i just want it to follow the where clause `value > -5` and then on the second case `MIN(CASE WHEN id = '002' THEN value END) Col2` i want it to follow just the `value > -5` ?